# Why do I need parentheses around arrow function regardless of the ESLint configuration rules?

Tags: javascript, parameters, eslint, eslintrc

I set up the .eslintrc.json file in my react project as follow.

```
{
"env": {
    "browser": true,
    "commonjs": true,
    "es2021": true,
    "node": true,
    "jest": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "airbnb-base",
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended"
  ],
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true,
      "jsx": true
    },
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaVersion": "latest"
  },
  "plugins": [
    "react"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "react/display-name": [
      "off"
    ],
    "no-console": [
      "warn",
      {
        "allow": [
          "clear",
          "infor",
          "error",
          "dir",
          "trace"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "no-useless-return": "error",
    "linebreak-style": [
      "error",
      "unix"
    ],
    "quotes": [
      "error",
      "single"
    ],
    "indent": [
      "error",
      2
    ],
    "semi": [
      "error",
      "always"
    ],
    "arrow-parens": ["error", "as-needed"],
    "comma-dangle": [
      "error",
      "never"
    ]
  }
}
```

But I run my application and then get below error from eslint.

[image: This stands like a syntax error.]

Please help me with how do I have to change my eslint rule or code base.

[I was referred from this link.](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/arrow-parens)

Comment: Show an example of your code, please.

Comment: something like this: `(a, b, c) => { ...... };` is only valid when parentheses are used, regardless of your eslint config.

Comment: ES6 requires multiple arguments to _always_ be wrapped. This isn't an ESLint issue. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#syntax.